# how to save the modified content of android content view?

Tags: android, xml, save

I have implemented an application with multiple check boxes with multiple layouts.I am invisible the layouts when user unchecked the related check box.then i am trying to save the content and settings when user re-launch the application.

I have implemented code as follows:

```
public class MultipleControllsActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

LinearLayout l1,l2,l3;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    l1 = ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1));
    l2 = ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2));
    l3 = ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout3));

    ((CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if(!isChecked){
            l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);    
            }
        }
    });


    ((CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });


    ((CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox3)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            l3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });


    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.saveTemp)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Save the content code here

        }
    });

}
```

}

When i click on the saveTemp button then i would like to save the content and if user re-launch the application then the saved content will be appear.

please any body help me...

Comment: Can you please explain you question more vividly. From what I understand, you want to store the state of CheckBox so that the next time the user starts the app it should start as it was. Is that right or do you meant something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

SharedPreferences

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Use This :--

```
     public class MultipleControllsActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    LinearLayout l1,l2,l3;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
     SharedPreferences pref_settings;
    pref_settings = getSharedPreferences("DATA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        l1 = ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1));
        l2 = ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2));
        l3 = ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout3));
l1.setVisibility(pref_settings.getInt("l1", 0));
l2.setVisibility(pref_settings.getInt("l2", 0));
l2.setVisibility(pref_settings.getInt("l3", 0));

        ((CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if(!isChecked){
                l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);    
                }
            }
        });


        ((CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


        ((CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox3)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                l3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.saveTemp)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                SharedPreferences pref_settings;
    pref_settings = getSharedPreferences("DATA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref_settings.edit();


                editor.putInt("l1", l1.getVisibility());
    editor.putInt("l2", l2.getVisibility());
    editor.putInt("l3", l3.getVisibility());

                editor.commit();

            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what I had implemented using a Multiple Choice ListView, even though I do not use CheckBoxes directly you might get a slight idea as of how to go ahead..
You can save your preferences like this...

```
public void SaveSelections() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sp.edit();
    String savedItems = getSavedItems();
    prefEditor.putString(LOAD_LIST, savedItems);
    prefEditor.commit();
}

private String getSavedItems() {
    String savedItems = "";
    int count = listView.getAdapter().getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (listView.isItemChecked(i)) {
            if (savedItems.length() > 0) {
                savedItems += "," + listView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            } else {
                savedItems += listView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return savedItems;
}
```

Here is a method for loading your selections..

```
private void LoadSelections() {
        SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (sp.contains(LOAD_LIST)) {
            String savedItems = sp.getString(LOAD_LIST, "");
            this.selectedItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(savedItems.split(",")));
            int count = this.listView.getAdapter().getCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                String currentItem = (String) listView.getAdapter().getItem(i);
                if (this.selectedItems.contains(currentItem)) {
                    this.listView.setItemChecked(i, true);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Then in OnCreate call LoadSelections() like this so that ...

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
checkedItems = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
final int checkedItemsCount = checkedItems.size();
lst = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < checkedItemsCount; ++i) {
// This tells us the item position we are looking at
final int position = checkedItems.keyAt(i);
final String str2 = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
lst.add(str2);
}
SaveSelections();
```

Finally call LoadSelections in OnCreate like this

> LoadSelections();